# Gradle task error occurred in android studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

My project was running successfully. But suddenly I am getting the following error after the build finished.

Can anyone tell me what is going on here? I have no idea about this error. How should I fix it?

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.1/cardview-v7-23.2.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.1/cardview-v7-23.2.1.jar
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.1/cardview-v7-23.2.1.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.1/cardview-v7-23.2.1.jar
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.1/cardview-v7-23.2.1.pom
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.1/cardview-v7-23.2.1.jar
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.1/cardview-v7-23.2.1.pom
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.1/cardview-v7-23.2.1.jar
     Required by:
         FinderMaterial:app:unspecified
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.jar
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.jar
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.pom
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.jar
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.pom
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.jar
     Required by:
         FinderMaterial:app:unspecified > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.11.0
   > Could not find com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.1/cardview-v7-23.2.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.1/cardview-v7-23.2.1.jar
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.1/cardview-v7-23.2.1.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.1/cardview-v7-23.2.1.jar
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.1/cardview-v7-23.2.1.pom
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.1/cardview-v7-23.2.1.jar
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.1/cardview-v7-23.2.1.pom
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.1/cardview-v7-23.2.1.jar
     Required by:
         FinderMaterial:app:unspecified > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.11.0
   > Could not find com.android.support:customtabs:23.2.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/customtabs/23.2.1/customtabs-23.2.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/customtabs/23.2.1/customtabs-23.2.1.jar
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/customtabs/23.2.1/customtabs-23.2.1.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/customtabs/23.2.1/customtabs-23.2.1.jar
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/customtabs/23.2.1/customtabs-23.2.1.pom
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/customtabs/23.2.1/customtabs-23.2.1.jar
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/customtabs/23.2.1/customtabs-23.2.1.pom
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/customtabs/23.2.1/customtabs-23.2.1.jar
     Required by:
         FinderMaterial:app:unspecified > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.11.0
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.jar
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.jar
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.pom
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.jar
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.pom
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.jar
     Required by:
         FinderMaterial:app:unspecified > com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0
         FinderMaterial:app:unspecified > com.android.support:design:23.2.0
         FinderMaterial:app:unspecified > com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0
         FinderMaterial:app:unspecified > com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0 > com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.2.0
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.jar
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.jar
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.pom
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.jar
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.pom
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.jar
     Required by:
         FinderMaterial:app:unspecified > com.flipboard:bottomsheet-core:1.5.0
         FinderMaterial:app:unspecified > com.flipboard:bottomsheet-commons:1.5.0
         FinderMaterial:app:unspecified > com.github.citux:datetimepicker:0.2.0 > com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.jar
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.jar
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.pom
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.jar
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.pom
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.jar
     Required by:
         FinderMaterial:app:unspecified > com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not at my (correct) computer to check this but I'm pretty sure the support libraries are a download like any other SDK. Make sure you've got the correct version downloaded and installed. SDK Manager Tutorial if needed: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html
**EDIT:** It appears there is a 23.3.0 available so it might be that you upgraded the package and uninstalled 23.2.1. Options are, if that is the case, to grab back 23.2.1 or swap in 23.3.0 in your gradle code

Comment: paste contents of your build.gradle and settings.gradle

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should update your Android Repository do to it:

1. Open SDK Manager
2. Android Support Repository
3. Install packages

[image]

In Android Studio 2.0, you can find this in:

**Tools -> Android -SDK Manager** menu option.

Once the dialog opens, open **Apearance and Behavior > System settings > Android SDK**, and then select the *second* tab, **SDK Tools**.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fix it from command line (maybe for automated build server like my case):

`echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --filter extra-android-m2repository --force --all`